# detect click on link in Firefox

Tags: javascript, events, firefox-addon, onclick

I want to detect in my firefox extension if a link has been clicked. So far, for this I add a click event listener to the window

```
  window.addEventListener("click", function(event) { handleWindowClick(event); }, false);

  ...

  handleWindowClick : function(event)  {
    if ("event.target is a link") {
      // do something
    }
  };
```

For some links the event.target is simple the URL. However, for some links I get, e.g., a HTMLSpanElement as event.target. Am I on the right track to catch link clicks or are there other ways? If it works this way, how can I ensure the successfully test if the event.targer is a link?

Answer (score 2):

You're adding an event listener to the main window which registers any click. The url's you're having problems with must be wrapped in a `<span>` tag. What you need is [event delegation](http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate)

Comment: Thanks for the link! Yes, something like this I thought it might be. But it looks like I more or less have to know the HTML structure right? The links where I get an HTMLSpanElement as event.target look like this: `<a href="..."><span>Text</span></a>`. But what happens if there a arbitrary constructs with SPANs and DIVs. And I don't think I can go down recursively since at one point I might also find a link.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just put the click event listener to anchors (`<a>`)?

```
var hrefs = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

for (i = 0; i < hrefs.length; i++) {
    hrefs[i].addEventListener(...)
    ...
}
```

or in [jQuery](http://jquery.com/):

```
$('a').click(function () {
    ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've already seen this solution. It just looks a bit like 'overkill', particularly since I don't really have to differ between the links. I just want to test if it is a link. But perhaps I'll settle with this approach.

Comment: @Christian, many programmers spend most time optimizing things that matter least. :-)

Comment: For the time being I will use this solution. It's the only one with which I get the result I had in mind. @Tomas: You're probably right! I actually have no idea what it means from a performance perspective if a page has a very large number of links. It just _looks_ unnecessary to me :).

Comment: @Christian, actually you are right, I had these problems on page that contained 500+ links (a jquery tree with folded branches), which took like 0.5s (don't remember) to run the script, so I made special optimization just for this page... but in 99% cases it's not a problem.

Answer (score 1):

check this out, i hope this is what you are looking for.

```
window.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    handleWindowClick(event);
}, false);

function handleWindowClick(event){
   var origEl = event.target || event.srcElement;
    if(origEl.tagName === 'A')
       alert("anchor link is clicked");
    else if(origEl.parentNode.tagName === 'A')
         alert("clicked inside anchor");
    else if(origEl.tagName === 'SPAN')
        alert("span  is clicked");
}
```

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/5zXkN/3/

Comment: Thanks for your post! It works, of course, as it supposed to work. The problem is that it fails for my needs for links like `<a href="..."><span>Link Text</span></a>`, and normal texts like `<span>Normal Text</span>`. Both clicks result in "span is clicked", but the one is a link the other is not.

Comment: if origEl.tagName == span, loop th. the parentNodes to see if it is a anchore tag until u reach the body or some common tag to confirm this span is not in a anchor.

Comment: Yeah absolutely.. you can check the parent Node.. i have updated the code and example as well. Check that if it solve your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I  extended the answer of dku.rajkumar to support arbitrary constructs within "A"-tags. I'm simply go up the tree until I either find an "A" or I'm at the root (so no link clicked in this case). It seems to do the trick. Thanks to all for your help!

```
 window.addEventListener("click", function(event) { handleWindowClick(event); }, false);
 ...

 isLink : function(element) {
   if(element.tagName === 'A')
     return true;
   else 
     if (element.parentNode) 
       return this.isLink(element.parentNode)
     else
       return false;
 },

 handleWindowClick : function(event) {
   var element = event.target || event.srcElement;
   var isLink = this.isLink(element);
   if (isLink) 
     dump("A link has been clicked.\n");
 },
```